# How to build Tabs component Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm trying to build a Tabs component with ReactJS and I'm following a CSS stylesheet.So, I would love to have this as render :

```
<div data-container="" class="tabs tabs-horizontal">
    <div class="tabs-header">
        <div class="tabs-header-tab ph active" data-tab="0" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px);">Personal
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-header-tab ph undefined" data-tab="0" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px);">Job
        </div>
        <div class="tabs-header-tab ph undefined" data-tab="0" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateZ(0px);">
            Salary</div>
    </div>
    <div data-container="" class="tabs-content">
        <div data-container="" class="tabs-content-tab open" data-tab="0">
            <div>I am a HR Specialist.</div>
        </div>
        <div data-container="" class="tabs-content-tab undefined" data-tab="0">
            <div>No records have been added yet</div>
        </div>
        <div data-container="" class="tabs-content-tab undefined" data-tab="0">
            <div>This type of information needs to be added by your manager</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is what the components looks like now :

```
<Tabs>
  <TabHeaders>
    <TabHeadersItem text="Personal" state="active" />
    <TabHeadersItem text="Job" />
    <TabHeadersItem text="Salary" />
  </TabHeaders>
  <TabContents>
    <TabContentsItem
      content="I am a HR Specialist."
      open="open"
    />
    <TabContentsItem content="No records have been added yet" />
    <TabContentsItem content="This type of information needs to be added by your manager" />
  </TabContents>
</Tabs>
```

So, I'm trying to find a solution, when user clicks on a header it becomes "active" and its content "open" while the others should be closed and not active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so since you've edited your question, I'll do with mine. The idea is the same: To keep the state of which tab is open, and since you don't want to keep your tabs in a list, then you need to link a TabHeader to a TabContent:

```js
const TabHeaderItem = props => {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={() => props.changeTab(props.text.toLowerCase())}
      className={props.state ? "active" : ""}
    >
      {props.text}
    </div>
  );
};

const TabContentsItem = props => {
  return <div className={props.open ? "open" : "closed"}>{props.content}</div>;
};

const TabComponent = () {
  const [active, setActive] = useState("personal");
  const changeTab = tab => {
    console.log("tab", tab);
    setActive(tab);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="tabs">
        <TabHeaderItem
          changeTab={changeTab}
          text="Personal"
          state={active === "personal"}
        />
        <TabHeaderItem
          changeTab={changeTab}
          text="Job"
          state={active === "job"}
        />
        <TabHeaderItem
          changeTab={changeTab}
          text="Salary"
          state={active === "salary"}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="tabs-content">
        <TabContentsItem
          content="I am a HR Specialist."
          open={active === "personal"}
        />
        <TabContentsItem
          content="No records have been added yet"
          open={active === "job"}
        />
        <TabContentsItem
          content="This type of information needs to be added by your manager"
          open={active === "salary"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can check out the working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-gauss-lbghq

Comment: Hello and thank you for this solution. But can we make it more.. let's say general. Here the user should put some functions in the tab component. The main goal of this is that the user put the components needed with their props and render to have Tabs component working.

Comment: My previous solution was based on a list of tabs that could be a settings or a JSON previously read from somewhere, so it was more generic than this solution. It seems to be that you have some specific requirements on how exactly needs to be implemented cuz none of these worked for you.